# Javascript object to HTML transform function

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, javascript-objects

I'm looking for a function which can transform:

```
{ tag: 'form',
  inner: [
    { tag: 'input', params: { type: 'text' } },
    { tag: 'select',
      inner: [
        { tag: 'option', params: { value: 0 },
          inner: ['zero']
        },
        { tag: 'option', params: { value: 1 },
          inner: ['one']
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

into:

```
<form>
  <input type="text"></input>
  <select>
    <option value="0">zero</option>
    <option value="1">one</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

I'm not looking for a templating system such as handlebars.

I'm flexible about the Javascript object's required property names, etc. - it's just an example of the JS representation of HTML that I want to be able to build up and modify, before "rendering" to HTML.

---

I'm not asking anyone to write code - I'd just like to know if there is an *existing* function that I'm not aware of.

---

Please don't write code for this.  Especially code that uses the DOM, as this is a server-side question and I've previously had nasty issues with NodeJS's fake DOMs.

Comment: the `inner` is the array of children

Comment: *"'m looking for a function"* - Have you tried *writing* a function?

Comment: @FrancescoE. I knew that. What I meant was what it was doing in `option` OP now clarified it through his edit

Comment: @nnnnnn yes, of course I could write it, comment it, and maintain it - but it looks like a common enough task that there might be something I can reuse.  If I don't get an answer, I'll write it and post it here.

Comment: @nnnnnn http://json2html.com/ is just what I was looking for - so now there is less code in the world to maintain ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no built-in implementation of such a function. However I've found this after a quick search on Google: http://json2html.com/

Seems pretty much similar to what you'are asking for.